# Are there any other frameworks that parse XSD other than XSOM?

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xsd

I have a requirement to verify if the constraints imposed by the XSD are in sync with the constraints enforced by the database. I am wondering if there are other frameworks that can help me in this regard other than XSOM.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [eclipse XSD project](http://www.eclipse.org/xsd/) is quite good for this too. Any code you write against it can be used [outside eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-XSD-FAQ#Can_the_XSD_library_be_used_outside_of_the_Eclipse_environment.3F).

Answer (score 0):

Another library to consider is [Apache XmlSchema](http://ws.apache.org/commons/XmlSchema/index.html).  You can use it to read a schema for analysis or modification and XmlSchema can also be used to create a new schema from scratch.