# All mandatory field in a xsd file?

Tags: xsd

Is there a quick way to find out all the mandatory field in a xsd file?

I need to quickly see all the mandatory fields in the schema

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking to do this through code.  If not, Altova XMLSpy, for example, provides an option to "Generate Sample XML File" - with options to generate only mandatory fields.

Otherwise, if you're working with Java, for example, you can use something like the [Eclipse XSD](http://www.eclipse.org/xsd/) project for programmatic access to the XSD.  (It even works without Eclipse.)  Some additional details at [Are there any other frameworks that parse XSD other than XSOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665900/are-there-any-other-frameworks-that-parse-xsd-other-than-xsom) .

Comment: I have not got altova.Any other option

Comment: You could use the free trial for a few days.

Comment: ok I am going to do that .Is it easy to find "Generate sample file with mandatory field? I am working in .net

Comment: The "Generate" option is under the main DTD/Schema menu.

Comment: Hi ,downloaded it cannot find the option with mandatory field? pressing "generate sample xml " views the doc immediately no option offered. any ideas

Comment: This is the option you're looking for:  http://manual.altova.com/xmlspy/spystandard/index.html?generatesamplexmlfile.htm

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378648/xsd-structure-to-csv-as-path-type-cardinality); instead of exporting all fields, there's also an option to get only the mandatory ones... One significant difference compared with the answer you accepted is in that you can also generate an Excel or CSV file, in addition to the XML file; not to mention that the sample XML approach is deficient by definition... I would pay attention to the way mandatory choices, abstract typed elements or abstract elements with substitution groups play in your case.